# Understanding java compilation and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm reading `JMH` samples and now I'm at the section about [***inheritance***](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/cb9aa824b55a/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_24_Inheritance.java). Here is the remark they made:

> because ***we only know the type hierarchy during the compilation***, it is
>   only possible during the same compilation session. That is, mixing in
>   the subclass extending your benchmark class *after* the JMH
>   compilation would have no effect.

I haven't thought of this aspect of compilation and so this doesn't seem quite clear to me. We could use [`Class::getSuperClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--) though. Example:

```
@Benchmark
public abstract class MyBenchmark{
    public void mb(){
        doSome();
    }

    public abstract doSome();
}
```

I thought that when compiling this class JHM uses annotation processor for benchmark generation. And then if we try to compile a subclass say

```
public class MyConcreteBenchmark extends MyBenchmark {
    @Override
    public void doSome(){
        //Do some
    }
}
```

it has no effect because annotation processor has nothing to process.

Comment: This is commentary, not question.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik What do you mean? I just was confused by **we only know the type hierarchy during the compilation**. What would it supposed to mean?

Comment: Annotation processor runs at compile time, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JHM comes before compiling (analyze and generate). Something like preprocessor or precompiler. 
Therefore jmh can not see the inheritance tree and it is not possible to see inherited annotations.

[Lombock](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok) for example works in the same way. Here is an image demonstrating how it works (just replace in mind Lombok by JMH):

[image]

Readmore: [Project Lombok: Creating Custom Transformations](http://notatube.blogspot.de/2010/12/project-lombok-creating-custom.html)